# for文を使って画像を連続表示させたい

Tags: python

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

    コードをここに入力
    image_paths = glob.glob('test_data/test/' + "*.jpg")
    image_paths = [image_paths]

    for i in image_paths:
        img = Image.open(i)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:2957, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   2956 try:
-> 2957     fp.seek(0)
   2958 except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in image_paths:
----> 2     img = Image.open(i)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:2959, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   2957     fp.seek(0)
   2958 except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2959     fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2960     exclusive_fp = True
   2962 prefix = fp.read(16)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 1):

`image_paths = [image_paths]`の行を削除すれば動作が継続して状況が変化するでしょう。

その前の行の`image_paths = glob.glob('test_data/test/' + "*.jpg")`の結果がリストで通知されるので、`image_paths = [image_paths]`を行うと`image_paths`の内容がリストのリストになるため、質問のエラーが発生すると考えられます。

提示されたソースコードには表示する処理は書かれていないので単に時間が経過して終了するだけかもしれませんが。